# use different spellcheck language and change windows default Language

Tags: c#

Hi I want to create a small program to change windows default language while spell check the user input in any text area in windows. I know too many programs like MS Word or Word Pad, specially these online text editors have spell check  so no need to write it from 0 to 100 right?

My primary language for this project is English but I don't know can I use spell check for other languages like French, Arabic, Turkish etc.

I have this for changing language :

```
public struct LanguageHelper
{
    public static void SetLanguage2English()
    {
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
    public static void SetLanguage2French()
    {
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("Fr-FR"));
    }
}
```

I don't any new lead to use it for this project. Thanks in Advance for every hint or new lead  that can help me to complete my project.

Comment: to answer your first question. Yes, there is no need to write this program from scratch! if it's on the web, the textboxes and input elements use the browser's spellcheck capabilities.

Comment: tnx  for advice Rami  but in this case the program is windows form based and and need some language  spell check libraries db or something like that and using it as a resource  but i don't know how i can find this libraries and using those in my project ...